# FOR XML PATH always adds trailing space to value

Tags: sql-server

Using the FOR XML PATH structure to create a list of values,
I find that (annoyingly) it always adds a trailing space to selected values.

This ruins my attempts at providing my own delimiters - the trailing space is added *after* the column and delimiters have been concatenated.

For example:

```
SELECT country + '-' FROM countryTable...
```

results in the following string:

```
china- france- england-
```

Has anyone else seen this, and is there a way to stop it?

I don't think TRIM() will work, as that would be applied before the extra space is inserted...

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Thanks

Comment: Use `SELECT LEFT(columnName,LEN(ColumnName)-1)`

Comment: Can you show verifiable example? `select for xml` doesn't adds any spaces by itself. Probably problem lies somewhere else - spaces in countries names of something similar.

Comment: What if each value in `Country` column is having leading space

Comment: @radders, I think in your data results you have spaces that's why you are getting spaces between each countries. Please check the country columns data.
and My question is how you returning these data in a row by selecting one column(country) from Table countryTable. Can you please elaborate your question and query.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, thanks to John C and his sample query I found the culprit.

I had a `AS [data()]` clause after the column name/delimiter.

Removing that removed the trailing space.
I don't know how/why but it did...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the *data* inside the `country` column, What if each value in Country column is having leading space. For `XML PATH` does not add any space to the data

Try this

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(country)) + '-' FROM countryTable...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have leading/trailing spaces and/or CRLFs.  Perhaps this will help

```
Declare @countryTable table (country varchar(100))
Insert Into @countryTable values
(' china'),             -- leading space
(char(13)+'france'),    -- leading char(13)
(char(10)+'england')    -- leading char(10)


Select Value=Stuff((Select Distinct '-' + ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(country,char(13),''),char(10),''))) 
                      From  @countryTable 
                      Where 1=1
                      For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
Value
china-england-france
```

Comment: I can assure everyone that my CountryName column has neither leading nor trailing spaces (or any other whitespace character)...

Comment: @radders Good to know.  Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: @radders Have you tried my sample query? The XML should really correct it

Answer (score 0):

`FOR XML PATH` ... `AS [data()]` add to this [from MS Help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885(v=sql.90).aspx#Anchor_4)

> If the path specified as column name is `data()`, the value is treated as an atomic value in the generated XML. A space character is added to the XML if the next item in the serialization is also an atomic value. This is useful when you are creating list typed element and attribute values.

When you write here ... AS *something*. Then *something* is used as open/closing markup tag for each selected value.

Add 2. Is possible concate in select clausule more fileds from each row. For other types than string type, value must be converted into string type `CAST AS`